# Sonarqube showing as bug on the return type in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am running sonarqube and fixing the errors. Actually most of the async methods which we used in our project we are returning void. But in the sonar report it is throwing error that it should return Task instead of void. When I changed the void to Task and executed sonar it is throwing error as "the method has the wron return type.

Can anybody please help me on this.

```
 private async void OnNextBtnClick()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (condition)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        _loadingService.ShowProgressBar();
                        if (_connectionService.CheckOnline())
                        {
                            fun();
                            CreatedTransactionRequest request =
                                new CreatedTransactionRequest
                                {
                                    --------------------------

                                };

                            var response = await _orderDataService.GetCreatedTransactionDetails(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

                            var navFlag = HandleNavigationBasedOnResponse(response);
                            if (navFlag == Convert.ToInt16(NavigationType.CreateDropOff))
                            {
                                ShowScheduleDropOneScreen();
                                _loadingService.HideProgressBar();
                            }
                            else if (navFlag == Convert.ToInt16(NavigationType.DropOffDialog))
                            {
                                ShowDropoffDialogScreen();
                                _loadingService.HideProgressBar();
                            }
                            else if (navFlag == Convert.ToInt16(NavigationType.TransactionDialog))
                            {
                                ShowTransactionDialogScreen();
                                _loadingService.HideProgressBar();
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _loadingService.HideProgressBar();
                            await _dialogService.ShowAlertAsync(TextSource.GetText("NetworkError"), TextSource.GetText("Error"),
                                TextSource.GetText("ok"),
                                Constants.AlertType.Error).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {


                          ----------------------------------

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _loadingService.HideProgressBar();
                    await _exceptionHandlerService.HandleErrorAsync(ex).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Void methods do not have a return type!!

Comment: yeah in sonar report it is throwing error as " in place of void return type should be Task as it is async task"

Comment: Then make it a Task what is the problem there exactly

Answer (score 0):

Well from my understanding of the situation you are trying to convert a void method to Task it's very easy without any change of code

Something like this :

```
  private async Task yourMehtod()
    {          
       await Task.Factory.StartNew(async() => { await yourVoidMethod(); });
    }
```